# Chronicle Wire message parser example

Tags: chronicle

I am using grizzly framework right now and looking for a way to improve latency of our exchange direct market access connection.

Our exchange message format is something like this:

- fixed length header
- type of message and length of payload are stored in header
- fix length String field (e.g. allocating fixed 20 bytes for a string field)

In grizzly I can easily create a message parser like this example:
https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/coreframeworksamples.html#/Parsing_an_incoming_message

I am looking for an example or tutorial on how to create same parser in Chronicle-Network and Wire.

Updated:

How to read / write a String from / into Wire with fixed length allocated? say writing '12345678' into a fixed 20 bytes space. The string will packed at first 8 bytes and the remaining 12 bytes will be filled with NULL bytes.

Here is my codes. It works but I believe it is not the proper approach.

```
private static final byte START_OF_MESSAGE = 0x02;

private int length;

private String compId;

@Override
public void readMarshallable(WireIn in) throws IORuntimeException {

    in.bytes().readByte();

    // first field
    length = in.bytes().readInt();

    // second field
    byte[] b = new byte[LENGTH_COMP_ID];
    in.bytes().read(b);
    compId = new String(b).trim();
}

@Override
public void writeMarshallable(WireOut out) {
    out.bytes().writeByte(START_OF_MESSAGE);

    // first field
    out.bytes().writeInt(length);

    /** second field, converting the string to byte[] */
    out.bytes().write(getBytes(compId, LENGTH_COMP_ID));
}

/**
 * retrieve a byte array of str with length = len
 */
private byte[] getBytes(String str, int len) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    if (str.length() > len) {
        return str.substring(0, len).getBytes();
    } else {
        byte[] b2 = str.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < b2.length ; i++) {
            b[i] = b2[i];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the test cases in Wire, If you would like a tutorial we do offer paid training courses please contact sales@chronicle.software

Comment: Thanks to your quick reply I will look into your test case folder again.